# Pending lightning network transaction for over 30hours

Tags: lightning-network, cash-app

I sent a Btc transaction from cash app Btc wallet to my exodus lightning network wallet using the lightning network.  The payment was made around 1:00pm central time on Monday, July 24.  Have spoken with cash app and they tell me “there is nothing we can do”. Before, and after, this attempted payment, I sent multiple payments on the lightning network to my exodus wallet without any real issue.  The transaction sent after the stuck pending one im writing about took longer than usual, but still completed within 15 mins.  Is there anything I can do, or need to do, in order to allow the pending transaction to either drop off and fall back into my cash app wallet or proceed to its destination in my exodus wallet.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: 1st you can wait for timelocks and 2nd you could provide details about the payment so that we can help debug. Cashapp team is most likely right though

Answer (score -1):

I had ~0.0001 BTC lost the abyss recently as well, vanished from sending via CashApp to a lightning invoice.  Got stuck in Pending in CashApp.  I ignored it for a few days, checked just now and it properly canceled itself on CashApp side.  When it was stuck in Pending, the amount being sent was subtracted from the bitcoin balance before the send attempt.  Now that it canceled itself, the original BTC balance is back in my bitcoin wallet.  Lightning Network = not yet perfect, but better than having to deal with banks.